# Reading from stdout using file pointer and decrementing it

Tags: c, pointers, stdout

I am trying to analyze the following piece of code:

```
FILE* out=stdout;
    
    printf("\nEnter value: \n");
    
    out=out-1;
    
    char ch;
    
    while(ch!=EOF){
        ch=fgetc(out);
        printf("\nValue printed: %c\n",ch);
    }
    
    fclose(out);
```

The following output is observed when I run this code:

```
Enter value:
IWantToC

Value printed: I

Value printed: W

Value printed: a

Value printed: n

Value printed: t

Value printed: T

Value printed: o

Value printed: C

Value printed:
```

I understand that fgetc is fetching the value from out(which is pointing to stdout) one character at a time and printing it till it reaches the file end.

What is out=out-1 doing here? If out was originally pointing to the beginning of the stdout file, then shouldn't it be printing chars from "Enter value:" as well. Or if it is pointing to the end of the stdout file, then shouldn't it be printing only one character from the end? Also, why is it expecting user input in the first place? Is it because of getc?

Sorry for the many questions. If someone clarifies those doubts, it will be very helpful for me to understand C. I have seen related questions here but haven't found any particularly addressing my queries.

Comment: Where did you find this code?  It is a very, very, very poor and misleading bit of code.  Out of the millions of lines of C code out there in the world, these are some of the last ones you should be spending any of your precious time studying or trying to learn from.

Comment: `while (c != EOF)` ==> Here, the value of `c` is indeterminate because it was never initialized.

Comment: Hi @SteveSummit, I wrote this myself, trying to figure out how things work and trying to analyze the outcome. When I wrote, it, I did not understand that it was a poor piece of code. I was just trying things out.

Comment: Hi @Haris, but it is not EOF as well, so I guess the condition should hold true?

Comment: @NeuronB - No, an "indeterminate" value cannot even be read. The only thing allowed is to assign it a value. Also, you can *never* learn the language by writing random code and "see what happens". As soon as you do something that is not allowed, the compiler is off the hook and can do just *anything*. See [Nasal Demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @NeuronB Okay, well, then let me correct a couple of misconceptions.  (1) In general, output streams like `stdout` are for output, and input streams are for input.  You should never be trying to read from an output stream.  Just those first three words in your question's title, "Reading from stdout", should be setting off alarm bells.

Comment: (2) Doing arithmetic on pointers — like subtracting 1 from the pointer `out` — is a useful and powerful technique in C, but it *only* makes sense if the pointer is known to point into an *array* of adjacent elements.  But after saying `out = stdout`, it makes no sense to be doing pointer arithmetic on `out`.  So whatever you thought you were learning or doing or analyzing in (1) and (2), please discard those particular avenues of inquiry, as they're likely to be quite meaningless.

Comment: Thanks @SteveSummit, I need to learn more about pointer arithmetics and how they operate. Thanks for your suggestions and guidance. It's much appreciated and much seeked by for a newbie :)

Answer (score 5):

It's undefined behavior.

On *some* systems (i.e. `libc` variant), the three standard streams are defined in an array (e.g):

```
FILE __stdlist[3];

#define stdin  (&__stdlist[0])
#define stdout (&__stdlist[1])
#define stderr (&__stdlist[2])
```

That's why it *seems* to work. Because with:

```
FILE *out = stdout;

out = out - 1;
```

Now, `out` is `stdin`.

But, this is just *one* `libc`. It can totally different with other systems. There is *no* requirement [or *guarantee*] that the `FILE` descriptors are in contiguous memory.

If you had (e.g.):

```
FILE *stderr;
int x;
FILE *stdout;
int y;
FILE *stdin;
int z;
```

Then, the "trick" would *not* work.

Do ***not*** use this.

---

*Side note:* Change `char ch;` into `int ch;`. Otherwise, if you got a legitimate 0xFF on the input, it would erroneously be interpreted as -1 (i.e. `EOF`).

---

**UPDATE:**

> On a system where the standard streams are defined in an array, as shown in your first example, the behavior of the OP's code is perfectly well defined, and should be expected to work reliably, so an unqualified "It's undefined behavior" is incorrect. However, it is unspecified whether the behavior is defined, and a program that relies on that behavior does not conform strictly to the language spec. –
> John Bollinger

So, if I said *unspecified*, things would be okay? How would one reliably detect this?

Even on `glibc` [which *does* this--I checked], how does one know unless we do `#ifdef __GLIBC__` or some such.

Otherwise, I think we must assume `stdout` points to a *single* instance. If we do:

```
int val;
int *ptr = &val;
ptr = ptr - 1;
```

[Without consulting the spec] I think that's UB.

We could just as easily have:

```
FILE *__stdlist[3];

#define stdin  (__stdlist[0])
#define stdout (__stdlist[1])
#define stderr (__stdlist[2])
```

And, the array elements are initialized from (e.g.) `malloc` + some setup.

And, again it won't work.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> please correct me if I am wrong in understanding your answer. So, when I write out=out-1, it goes into stdin and waits for user input.

For terminology, I'm not sure I would say "*goes* into `stdin`". I'd say it "*points* to `stdin`" or "is set to the value of `stdin`".

> After I give the input, it reads from the same stdin input and prints out the characters one by one. Is that correct? –
> NeuronB

At that point, using the "trick" [which, you *can't* use], we have `out` pointing to the same address as `stdin` points to. So, the *clean* way to do this is:

```
FILE *out = stdin;
```

After that, this is just a simple *loop* that:

1. reads one char from the `out` stream [which is *now* `stdin`]
2. if the char read is `EOF`, the loop is ended.
3. prints it to the display (i.e. `stdout`).

Comment: On a system where the standard streams are defined in an array, as shown in your first example, the behavior of the OP's code is perfectly well defined, and should be expected to work reliably. The unqualified "It's undefined behavior" is therefore incorrect.  Rather, whether the behavior is defined is *unspecified*, and a program that relies on that behavior does not conform strictly to the language spec.  Any way around, however, such code absolutely should not be used, I agree. It is abominable.

Comment: Hi @CraigEstey, please correct me if I am wrong in understanding your answer. So, when I write out=out-1, it goes into stdin and waits for user input. After I give the input, it reads from the same stdin input and prints out the characters one by one. Is that correct?